# Translation of a sentence from English to Italian

Tags: translation, english-comparison

I would like to give some present to my Italian friend and I would like to write on this present the following: "with all my heart and love". Could please someone translate this into Italian?

My version is "con tutto il cuore e amore" but I am beginner in Italian language and it could be incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE. Note that translation requests like this one [are generally considered off-topic](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic).

Comment: This site is not to be intended as a translation service. You should provide an attempt of translation by yourself and then ask if it is correct. This question without the suggested improvements will be considered off topic and then closed.

Comment: @abarisone, sorry for off topic, I wrote my variant of translation

Comment: @Charo I think it could be reopened.

Comment: @abarisone: Do you know that you can vote to reopen the question?

Comment: @Charo Even from the app?

Comment: @abarisone: I think you will have to open the question in a web browser.

Comment: The OP is not “mentioning the exact issue, including your attempts at translation, and describing your doubts”. This is important, since otherwise one could hypothetically just give a translation made by Google Translate and ask us to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is ALMOST correct...

> With all **my** heart and love.

As you can see inside this sentence you find written "my", that is translated as "mio" (mine), which is missing from your translation:  "con tutto il MIO cuore e amore".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: English uses possessives more frequently than Italian. Translations need not be “literal”.